# Dependecy Injection Symfony dealing with multiple parameter

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony5

I'm actually trying to autowiring a class which purpose is to build query.
the class constructor looked like this :

```
#App\Services\RepositoryDirector
class RepositoryDirector
{

    public function __construct(BuilderQueryRepositoryInterface $builderQueryRepository, FilterInterface $filter)
    {
        $this->_builderQueryRepository = $builderQueryRepository;
        $this->_filter = $filter;
    }
}
```

Notice that both parameter are Interface so it may change depending on where I implement the RepositoryDirector.

I have try to implement this object in two controller called ProductController, and CartController.

```
# App\Controller\ProductController 
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    private RepositoryDirector $_cartRepositoryDirector;

    public function __construct(ProductRepository $productRepository, ProductFilter $productFilter)
    {
        $this->_productRepositoryDirector = new RepositoryDirector($productRepository, $productFilter);
    }

    // Controller logic
```

```
# App\Controller\CartController 
class CartController extends AbstractController
{
    private RepositoryDirector $_cartRepositoryDirector;

    public function __construct(CartRepository $cartRepository, CartFilter $cartFilter)
    {
        $this->_cartRepositoryDirector = new RepositoryDirector($cartRepository, $cartFilter);
    }

    // Controller logic
```

But the problem is that I don't use auto wiring here, and this is strongly coupled as I don't use DI.

What I would like to have is something like that :

```
# App\Controller\ProductController 
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    private RepositoryDirector $_productRepositoryDirector;

    public function __construct(RepositoryDirector $productRepositoryDirector)
    {
        $this->_productRepositoryDirector = $productRepositoryDirector;
    }

    // Controller logic
```

So I have to configure `config/services.yaml` to tell Symfony that when I am using `$productRepositoryDirector` as an argument, I want that it create a new object `RepositoryDirector` with two parameters :

1. ProductRepository $productRepository
2. ProductFilter $productFilter

I was thinking about doing something like that :

```
App\Controller\ProductController:
    public: true
    arguments:
        $productRepositoryDirector: ['@App\Repository\ProductRepository', '@App\Services\ProductFilter']
```

But this is not working and I got the following error :

> Cannot autowire service "App\Services\RepositoryDirector": argument
> "$builderQueryRepository" of method "__construct()" references
> interface "App\Repository\BuilderQueryRepositoryInterface" but no such
> service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to one of these
> existing services: "App\Repository\AreaCodeRepository",
> "App\Repository\CompanyRepository", "App\Repository\DataRepository",
> "App\Repository\GroupRepository",
> "App\Repository\ParamStyleRepository",
> "App\Repository\ParamTypeDatasetRepository",
> "App\Repository\ParamTypeFormatRepository",
> "App\Repository\ParamTypeRepository",
> "App\Repository\ParameterGroupRepository",
> "App\Repository\ParameterRepository",
> "App\Repository\PhoneNumberRepository",
> "App\Repository\ProductRepository",
> "App\Repository\UserTokenRepository",
> "App\Repository\ValueRepository".

I have been reading [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces) but it is not providing any solution about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution.

You have to configure the `config/services.yaml` like this :

```
    #
    # Director repository services
    #
    app.services.repository_director.product:
        public: true
        class: App\Services\RepositoryDirector
        arguments:
            $builderQueryRepository: '@App\Repository\ProductRepository'
            $filter: '@App\Services\Filters\ProductFilter'

    app.services.repository_director.cart:
        public: true
        class: App\Services\RepositoryDirector
        arguments:
            $builderQueryRepository: '@App\Repository\CartRepository'
            $filter: '@App\Services\Filters\CartFilter'

    #
    # Controller
    #
    App\Controller\ProductController:
        public: true
        arguments:
            $productRepositoryDirector: '@app.services.repository_director.product'

    App\Controller\CartController:
        public: true
        arguments:
            $cartRepositoryDirector: '@app.services.repository_director.cart'
```

I was missing the `class` key word, which I have found by pure luck thank to PHPStorm autocompletion !

If you read [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring) Very attentively you'll notice that this keyword is using with usage of aliasing exactly as I did it in the code above.

Now I've been able to find a more precise documentation about this problem :  [Explicitly Configuring Services and Arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments).